# Is there any libraries could import contacts from hotmail/live/aol account?

Tags: python, api

I've import contacts from gmail by using gdata api, 
and is there any apis like that for hotmail/live/Aol ?

Answer (score 2):

There is Windows Live Contact API for Hotmail/Live mail.
Yahoo Contact API for Yahoo also exists, but to this date, no AOL contact api.

I would suggest you try openinviter (openinviter.com) to import contacts. Unfortunately, you will not have OAuth capabilities, but it is the best class out there and works with 90+ different email providers.

Note: it is written in php, but creating a wrapper won't be too hard.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to export from them to the standard vCard format, you can read and process vCard data using the [vobject](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/vobject) package.

Answer (score 1):

### Hotmail/Live

There is [Windows Live Contact API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb463989.aspx) for Hotmail/Live mail, which is similar to GData API.

### AOL

As far as I remember AOL doesn't provide API to access its address book, however they working on it (for long time)...